# Test Postgresql query on a table with JSON columns using Python

Tags: python, json, database, postgresql, jsonb

Example query:

```
SELECT error->>'message' as message
FROM error_cases
```

In reality, my query is way more complicated and I would like to make sure that future code changes won't destroy the data this query outputs. I would like to compare result of this query with some particular output I already have.
I am using `testing.postgresql` library to create temporary database, run the query, save the output and destroy the database.
My query uses Postgresql `->>` notation. I get the error:

```
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedFunction: operator does not exist: text ->> unknown
```

To reproduce, first I create table:

```
            cur.execute('CREATE TABLE error_cases (error TEXT NOT NULL)')
```

Then I insert data:

```
cur.execute('INSERT INTO error_cases 
             VALUES ('{"message": "someMessage"}')
```

And select:

```
select (error->>'message') as message from error_cases
```

I've looked at `sqlalchemy` to query the data, but the problem is that I want to test this particular query I have. In `sqlalchemy` for retrieving JSON I can't use Postgresql `->>` notation, which is in my query.
---Is there any other way to run query containing `->>` operator on database created using `testing.postgresql`?

Answer (score 1):

I've just located the issue, which is so basic - should be:
`CREATE TABLE error_cases (error JSONB NOT NULL)` instead of
`CREATE TABLE error_cases (error TEXT NOT NULL)`